# Docker tar command doesnt work

Tags: docker

I am trying to unzip samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2 using the tar command

```
tar -xjvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
```

I am able to run tar command without docker. but it gives me error when i try to untar it using docker. Can someone please help.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux
RUN yum -y install bzip2
WORKDIR  /sharedData
RUN echo "Installing SMTOOLS."
ADD https://sourceforge.net/projects/samtools/files/samtools/0.1.18/samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2 /sharedData

RUN tar -xjvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
```

Error:

```
Step 5/6 : ADD https://sourceforge.net/projects/samtools/files/samtools/0.1.18/samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2 /sharedData
Downloading 130.2 kB
 ---> c524de5863ce
Removing intermediate container 941f57797c7b
Step 6/6 : RUN tar -xjvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
 ---> Running in 0391b2f5bf9c
tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c tar -xjvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: I already tried to install bzip2 but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
FROM amazonlinux
WORKDIR  /sharedData
RUN yum install -y bzip2
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/samtools/files/samtools/0.1.18/samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2  
RUN tar -xjvf samtools-0.1.18.tar.bz2
```

Comment: @Peri461, indeed, ADD is mainly designed for downloading files.